# Creating shares in Snowflake on a trial account? Error that it does not exist

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was unable to alter  a share on my trial account.

I tried the following:

```
ALTER SHARE "SAMPLEDATA_SHARE" ADD ACCOUNTS = BBB12123;
```

And this was the error:

> Share 'SAMPLEDATA_SHARE' does not currently have a database. Database can be added using command 'GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE  TO SHARE SAMPLEDATA_SHARE'.

```
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE DEMO_DB TO SHARE SAMPLEDATA_SHARE;
```

as the accountadmin, and see an error that says it does not exist.

> SQL compilation error: Share '"xxx.SAMPLEDATA_SHARE"' does not
>   exist or not authorized.

Do I use the role of the creator of the share or another role I need to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to say a bit more about how your database and share are set (as in what role they were created with and what roles have permissions to them).

I was able to execute the 3 following commands successfully using accountadmin:

```
create or replace database db_sh;
create or replace share sh_sh;
grant usage on database db_sh to share sh_sh;
```

Comment: MMV, good point, I tried creating a share on data that I uploaded. the Sample Data looks like it was already shared to the trial account I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make sure that you run `use role accountadmin;`, before you run the *GRANT* command?
The role you use on your worksheet, could be different than the role you see on the upper corner.

Comment: Thank you Gokthan, I tried this and still got the "does not exist or not authorized error".